# Why div's position changes based on content?

Tags: css, html, position, height

I have a content div that loads different pages. I can't set fixed position to it because I want to scroll through it's content.

This div is loaded inside a 100% height table(#main). Problem is, if the content div has small content height(so scrollbar doesn't appear) my div moves below, like more top margin is applied. I want every page though to load on same y position.
What am I doing wrong?

Note that: Below #content there is a footer div with relative position on which I also don't want to apply fixed position property. It seems that the more the #footer is dragged down the page it is taking #content with it as well, since they are on same table row.

```
#main{
    width:1010px;
    height:100%;
}
#content{   
    margin-top:303px;
    padding: 35px;
}
#footer{
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Try using min-height on your div.

Comment: I am curious why you are using divs inside table rows for layout, please provide a sample of your html markup.

Comment: Table acts as a container, for shadowing of the layout and also adding borders on the sides(since I couldn't make this using divs succesfully). Here is the site: http://metallica-gr.net/index.html , click on the first article to enter and notice the div moving down. I have a js code that places the footer on bottom if the content height isn't scrollable.

Comment: @zefs, I would realy suggest looking a bit more for a css only solution for your layout. The table is going to give you lots of headaches. The reason why it is moving down is because the table cell is trying to align center vertically.

Comment: All the pages use the same layout, if I remove the table now I would need to do a lot of editing. Aren't there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `td` height is 100%, and you didn't set the `vertical-align` to `top`. So it default to `middle`. :

```
#main td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That's correct, thanks a lot! and was getting all frustrated about changing layout because of this. Cheers!